# Understanding matrix dimesions in printing CNN Heatmaps (for Class Activation Map" (CAM))

Tags: keras, printing, visualization, heatmap, conv-neural-network

This question is related to computing the `Class Activation Map (CAM) visualization`.
Source code is at [ln [24 and onwards]: [See ln [24] onwards and code snapshot pasted below](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/5.4-visualizing-what-convnets-learn.ipynb)

Model.summary()

[image]

The last convolutional layer is `block5_conv3` with dimensions `(14, 14, 512)` and it predicts `1000 classes`.

My questions are related to lines of code in this screenshot.
[image]

I included the lines of code separately also

1. In this line of code:

   `african_elephant_output = model.output[:, 386]`

   This model was trained on 1000 classes (the last line in the output of model.summary()). To understand the gradient calculation at a later step, I first want to understand how to print the length of vector `african_elephant_output`and also the actual values in this feature vector
2. `last_conv_layer = model.get_layer('block5_conv3')`

   `grads = K.gradients(african_elephant_output, last_conv_layer.output)[0]`

   The dimensions of `last_conv_layer` are `(14, 14, 512)`. But to understand how the dot product calculated by `K.gradients`, I need to know the dimensions of `african_elephant_output`. Should these dimensions of `African_elephant output` be: `(1, 1, 512)` so that we are able to first `broadcast` `African_elephant output` and then calculated the dot product of corresponding channels? How can  I `print` the dimensions of `african_elephant_output` and the dimensions and values of `grads`?
3. What does axis = (0, 1, 2) refer to this line of code:

   `pooled_grads = K.mean(grads, axis=(0, 1, 2))`

   I am assuming the `grads` vector in #2 above is of shape `(14, 14, 512)` so the    `axis` values of `0, 1, 2` refer to `width` (referred to by 0), `height` (referred to by 1) and the `channel` dimension ((referred to by 2). So that the mean is calculated along the width and height and we get a vector of `shape (512, )` ?

Comment: Hi - This would be so helpful..

Comment: For #3: I figured out this part. `grads` is of shape `(None, 14, 14, 512)`. So with axis = (0, 1, 2), we are calculating the mean along the dimensions 0,1,2. And therefore collapsing the vector along dimensions `0` (which is `None`), `dimension 1, which is 14` and `dimension 2, which is 2`. This leaves alone only the 4th dimension of length 512 `(the 512 channels)`. So the shape of `pooled_grads` is `(512, )`**

Comment: For #1: `TensorFlow version > 2.0` and `tf.executing_eagerly()` returns `true`. Even then, I can not print the value in `african_elephant_output` using `african_elephant_output.numpy()`.

Comment: Tried to print `african_elephant_output` indirectly:       
`print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds, top=3))
     # returned: Predicted: [[('n02504458', 'African_elephant', 0.90942043), ('n01871265', 'tusker', 0.08618348), ('n02504013', 'Indian_elephant', 0.004354588)]]
    print (african_elephant_output)
     # returned Tensor("strided_slice_9:0", shape=(None,), dtype=float32)
    print ("the length for the prediction vector is: " + str(len(preds[0])))
     # returned: 1000
    print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds, top=3)[0][0][2])
     # Predicted: 0.90942043`